# Mongo project test if value is in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, contains, projection

In a project step of a mongo aggregation, I'd like to create a boolean field like:

```
{
  $project: {
    isInArray: { $cond: [
      { $in: ['$_id', ids] },
      { $const: true },
      { $const: false },
    ] },
  },
},
```

but this is failing with

```
 invalid operator $in
```

I could not find documentation on the correct syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator

```
db.people.aggregate([
 { $project: {
    isInArray: { $cond: [ {$setIsSubset: [['$_id'], ids]}, true, false ] }
 }}
])
```

Comment: Do you know if there're performance downsides, like if there's an index in `_id` that might not get used by this ?

Comment: @Guig afaik aggregation can use indexes only for $match operation if it goes first